# How to write a "from" and "to" function for "Add Void a === a"?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

From the document: http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/, it says:

> Bool and Add () () are equivalent, because we can define a "from" and "to" function:
>
> ```
> to :: Bool -> Add () ()
> to False = AddL ()
> to True  = AddR ()
>
> from :: Add () () -> Bool
> from (AddL _) = False
> from (AddR _) = True
> ```
>
> That:
>
> ```
> from (to a) == a
> to (from a) == a
> ```

Then he gives another two:

```
 Add Void a === a
 Add a b === Add b a
```

How to write "from" and "to" functions for these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For

> Add a b === Add b a

you need to swap the `AddL/AddR` constructors as follows:

```
to :: Add a b -> Add b a
to (AddL x) = AddR x
to (AddR x) = AddL x

-- from = to
```

For

> Add Void a === a

you need a polymorphic function `void : Void -> a`

```
to :: Add Void a -> a
to (AddL impossible) = void impossible
to (AddR x) = x

from :: a -> Add Void a
from x = AddR x
```

The variable `impossible` stands for a "non-existent" value of type `Void`. There is indeed no such value (apart from bottom/undefinedness). This is why the line

```
to (AddL impossible) = ...
```

is actually unreachable code -- it will never be executed.

Function `void` exploits the fact that it requires an impossible argument to produce a value `a` out of thin air. Sadly, in Haskell, `void` can not be defined unless exploiting undefinedness, e.g.

```
void :: Void -> a
void _ = error "This will never be reached"
```

A more elegant and correct solution would have been

```
void :: Void -> a
void x = case x of
           -- no constructors for Void, hence no branches here to do!
           -- since all these (zero) branches have type `a`, the whole
           -- case has type `a` (!!!)
```

but, alas, Haskell forbids empty `case` constructs. (In GHC 7.8 empty cases are allowed through the [EmptyCase](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#empty-case) extension, as [bheklilr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839246/bheklilr) points out).

By comparison, in a dependently typed language such as Coq or agda the code above (with minor changes) would have been fine. Here's it in Coq:

```
Inductive Void : Set := .   (* No constructors for Void *)

Definition void (A : Set) (x : Void) : A :=
      match x with
      end .
```

And in Agda

```
data Void : Set where
   -- no constructors

void : (A : Set) -> Void -> A
void A ()         
-- () is an "impossible" pattern in Agda, telling the compiler that this argument
-- has no values in its type, so one can omit the definition entirely.
```

Comment: "but, alas, Haskell forbids empty `case` constructs."  Not anymore, in 7.8 we now have the [`EmptyCase` extension](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#empty-case), which gives an example specifically for `Void`.

Comment: I tried to call `to (AddL 1)`, but it reports: `No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal 1, The type variable `a0' is ambiguous`. How can I give it a correct parameter?

Comment: @Freewind Use `to (AddL (1::Int))` to specify the type for `1`. Haskelll is complaining because the context around the `1` does not allow to understand whether `1` should be a `Int`,`Double`, or any other numeric type.

Answer (score 4):

The [`void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void) library has an [`absurd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.6.1/docs/Data-Void.html) function with type `Void -> a`. It captures the "from false, everything follows" logical principle.

It can be used to remove a `Void` branch from sum types. Intuitively, if your type is either `a` or something impossible, then it is pretty much the same as `a`.

```
import Data.Void

foo :: Either Void a -> a
foo x = either absurd id x
```